# Eureka Client with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize one of my microservices using docker.

Below is the dokerfile content

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine   
LABEL maintainer="shardajaiswal@gmail.com"

RUN mkdir -p /test/service/master/input/
RUN mkdir -p /test/service/master/output/
VOLUME /test/service/master/input/
VOLUME /test/service/master/output/

EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/master-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} master-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","master-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I have created image using maven plugin successfully.

Now when I try to run the image using the below command on docker CLI the service is up and running fine

```
docker run -p 7070:8080 -e spring.cloud.config.username=username123
-e \spring.cloud.config.password=password123
-e \spring.cloud.config.failFast=true
-e \spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
-e \eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://username123:password123@10.XXX.21.161:31120/eureka/,http://username123:password123@10.XXX.147.171:31120/eureka/ 
-e \spring.profiles.active=staging,XYZServerName shardaspj:master-1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

With above command from command line, its able to connect to config server and also able to register with Eureka.

Now I want to run the service using docker-compose.yml file since I want to add certain other parameters as well to the configuration.

My docker-compose.yml file looks like below:-

```
version: '3.0'
services:
 master:
  container_name: master
  image: shardaspj:master-1.1-SNAPSHOT
  environment:
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME: username123
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD: password123
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAILFAST: 'true'
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_DISCOVERY_ENABLED: 'true'
   EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE-URL_DEFAULTZONE: http://username123:password123@10.XXX.21.161:31120/eureka/,http://username123:password123@10.XXX.147.171:31120/eureka/
   SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: staging,XYZServerName
 ports:
   - "7070:8080"
```

But on running the command docker-compose up on command line I am getting the below error and not able to connect to register on eureka and also not connecting to config server to fetch the configuration files.

```
master    | 2018-07-18 11:18:51.867  WARN [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connectio
n refused (Connection refused)
master    | 2018-07-18 11:18:51.873 ERROR [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MASTER/cd656dee7969:master - was unable to refresh its cach
e! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
master    |
master    | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1022)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:936)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:412)
master    |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:267)
master    |     at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:61)
master    |     at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:234)
master    |     at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f480408d.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>)
master    |     at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f480408d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cdb46f4f.invoke(<gener
ated>)
```

Also down the logs getting error:-

```
2018-07-18 11:18:51.876  WARN [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
2018-07-18 11:18:51.886  INFO [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Not registering with Eureka server per configuration
2018-07-18 11:18:51.951  INFO [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1531912731950 with initial instances count : 0

2018-07-18 11:18:53.381  WARN [master,,,] 1 --- [           main] lientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration : Could not locate configserver via discovery

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (registry)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstance(ConfigServerInstanceProvider.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.refresh(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:80)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.startup(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
```

Please help me with setting up the docker-compose.yml correctly.

Comment: The `docker run -e` option and the Docker Compose `environment:` section are _identical_, but you’re spelling the environment variables differently on the two paths.  Does it work if you pass the same environment variables both ways?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried both ways in both places, does not work with other way round. I read somewhere that compose file does not accept "." in environment variables passed instead should have "_" in between variable names. 
       SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: staging,XYZServerName   works in docker compose but spring.profiles.active=staging,XYZServerName does not work in compose file.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off blanking out all the values for the environment variables in your docker-compose file and putting them in a .env file at the same level as your docker-compose file. The format of this file is key=value, one per line. That way you can re-use your compose file in different environments.

Then do a docker-compose config to see how the environment variables are plugged into your docker-compose set up.

I think the issue you have is you are missing hyphens. Instead of this:

```
environment:
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD
   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAILFAST
```

You need something like this:

```
environment:
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAILFAST
```

Running docker-compose config after you've moved the values into .env will show if you've got it all working OK.

Comment: Adding environment variables with hyphen also does not work, it is not able to pick the information. environment:
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME = username123
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD = password123
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAILFAST = 'true'
   - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_DISCOVERY_ENABLED = 'true'
   - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE-URL_DEFAULTZONE = http://username123:password123@10.XXX.21.161:31120/eureka/,http://username123:password@10.XXX.147.171:31120/eureka/
   - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = staging,XYZ ServerName

Comment: Can you post your full docker-compose.yml file, your full .env file, and the output of docker-compose config ? Then we can see what is going on by testing it.